# Expected start of definition error in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to run the Scala code presented in [this math.stackexchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233656/albert-bernard-and-cheryl-popular-question-please-comment-on-my-theory/1238418#comment2843577_1238418) (please see the second answer), but seem to be running into issues in the line starting with `implicit def...`. The compiler is telling me `error: expected start of definition`.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

I should add that I'm using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_scala_online.php to run my code.

Comment: Are you sure you copy'n'pasted the whole code? For me the example works flawlessly.

Comment: Yes, I'm cp'ing the entire code, but somehow still get errors. The solution below works but now I get `expected class or object definition` error for `type Date = (String, Int)` as well as every instance of `val ...` below that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just tried your example on Scala REPL and it works for me as expected.

Move the `implicit def` to an object:

```
object MyImplicits {
  /** Pimp `Set[X]` with a few convenient operators */
  implicit def logicalSetOps[X](set: Set[X]) = new {
    def and(other: Set[X]) = set.intersect(other)
    def or(other: Set[X]) = set.union(other)
    def minus(other: Set[X]) = set.filterNot(other.contains)
  }
}
```

and then do:

```
import MyImplicits._
```

That should work for you.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. However, I run into another error. I get `expected class or object definition` error for `type Date = (String, Int)` as well as every instance of `val ...` below that...

Comment: Move all the lines from `type Date` till the end to an object that extends App as @Sascha had mentioned. Only classes, objects and traits are expected by the compiler as a start definition.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The code in that example is meant to be pasted either into a worksheet or into the REPL.

It should also work to paste it inside an

```
object MathApp extends App {
  // paste here
}
```

Then you can run *MathApp* as scala or java application.

Comment: Thank you for your help!