# How to map postgresql enum to scala play model and enum?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, enums, slick

I could find this question asked in many places but none of the methods which were described seemed to work for me.
I am just starting to explore Play with Scala (2.4.2) and so I started a simple and functional CRUD application following [this page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick). I created a Cat model and I want to add a status field in it with defined values (Awake, Sleeping, Dead). I created the postgresql enum easily with, added in an evolution :

```
CREATE TYPE cat_status AS ENUM ('awake', 'sleeping', 'dead');
```

Then, I tried to define an object extending Enumeration and as well, using trait like in the code found [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html#using-custom-scalar-types-in-queries), in my model file:
package models

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait CatStatus
case object Awake extends TaskStatus
case object Sleeping extends TaskStatus
case object Dead extends TaskStatus

implicit val catStatusTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[CatStatus, String](
      {
        case Awake => "awake"
        case Sleeping => "sleeping"
        case Dead => "dead"
      },{
        case "awake" => Awake
        case "sleeping" => Sleeping
        case "dead" => Dead
      }
    )



case class Cat(id: Long, name: String, age: Int, color: String, picture: String, race: String, status: CatStatus)
```

But when I run "activator compile" I get the following error:

```
[error] XXX/app/models/Cat.scala:10: expected start of definition
[error] implicit val catStatusTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[CatStatus, String](
[error]          ^
```

I tried moving the code within an object, like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014641/expected-start-of-definition-error-in-scala):

```
object myCatMapper{
implicit val catStatusTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[CatStatus, String](
      {
        case Awake => "awake"
        case Sleeping => "sleeping"
        case Dead => "dead"
      },{
        case "awake" => Awake
        case "sleeping" => Sleeping
        case "dead" => Dead
      }
    )
}
```

But then, I get this error message:

```
[error] XXX/app/models/Cat.scala:11: not found: value MappedColumnType
[error] implicit val catStatusTypeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[CatStatus, String](
[error]                                     ^
```

I tried to add "import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple.*" and/or "import scala.slick.lifted.*" but "object slick is not a member of package scala".

I would appreciate any help with how to achieve this simple thing.
Thank you all.

Comment: You should import `play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._` once you configured slick correctly with [play-slick](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick)

Comment: @JPMelanson: Thank you for the comment. However as mentioned in my post, I actually did follow this guideline and got a functional CRUD application. However I still cannot get this particular feature to work.
I tried the import that you mentioned and got "object Config is not a member of package play.api.db.slick".

Comment: I ran into some additional issues with this. Finally, I went with using enumeratum and saving the data in the database as string (easier to port to other db manager). But I'd still would like to know how to do it at some point.

Comment: Can we get a bigger snippet? What imports do you have? What's the definition of `CatStatus`? I think you missed `CatStatus.Value` in the mapping definition.